# Python multicore without communication

Tags: python, multiprocessing, recommendation-engine

I want to call a methode getRecommendations which just pickle recommendations to a specific user to a file. I used a code from a book which works. But I saw that only one core works and I want that all my cores do the work, because this would be much faster.

Here is the method.

```
def getRecommendations(prefs,person,similarity=sim_pearson):
    print "working on recommendation"
    totals={}
    simSums={}
    for other in prefs:
    # don't compare me to myself
        if other==person: continue
        sim=similarity(prefs,person,other)
        # ignore scores of zero or lower
        if sim<=0: continue
        for item in prefs[other]:
            # only score movies I haven't seen yet
            if item not in prefs[person] or prefs[person][item]==0:
                # Similarity * Score
                totals.setdefault(item,0)
                totals[item]+=prefs[other][item]*sim
                # Sum of similarities
                simSums.setdefault(item,0)
                simSums[item]+=sim
    # Create the normalized list
    rankings=[(total/simSums[item],item) for item,total in totals.items( )]
    # Return the sorted list
    rankings.sort( )
    rankings.reverse( )
    ranking_output = open("data/rankings/"+str(int(person))+".ranking.recommendations","wb")
    pickle.dump(rankings,ranking_output)
    return rankings
```

It is called via

```
for i in customerID: 
        print "working on ", int(i)
        #Make this working with multiple CPU's
        getRecommendations(pickle.load(open("data/critics.recommendations", "r")), int(i))
```

as you can see i try to make a recommendation to every customer. Which will be used later.

So how can i multiprocess this method? I don't get it by reading a few examples or even the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something (roughly, untested) like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
NUMBER_OF_PROCS = 5 # some number... not necessarily the number of cores due to I/O

pool = Pool(NUMBER_OF_PROCS)

for i in customerID:
    pool.apply_async(getRecommendations, [i])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

(this is assuming you only pass 'i' into getRecommendations, since the pickle.load should only be done once)

Comment: for what stand pool = Pool(4) i have to give the critics.recommendations to this method. cause i want to use it for severals things.

Comment: Surely reading the documentation for Pool will help :)

(note that there are many other ways of using multiprocessing to do what you want. You might prefer imap_unordered)

Answer (score 0):

The answer James gave is the correct one. I'm just going to add that, you will need to import the *multiprocessing* module via

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

And, the Pool(4) means that you want to create 4 "worker" processes that will work in parallel to perform your task.

Comment: can i take the real number of cores in any way, so i can just say Pool(numberOfCores-1) ?